# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery - still unsolved

Tags: jquery

I'm starting with the front end in Angular2 of a project, As you will see I created the folders and libraries, when I test it, in the console I get an error. I followed other threads but didn't solve my problem.

[I am loading jQuery before Bootstrap and still getting an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lsEW.png)

[This is the error on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aewv3.png)

Comment: You might want to double check that you are loading jquery with a y instead of a u...

Comment: did you check Network tab in the browser inspector to verify if jquery is being loaded? Also, i've noticed a typo: you wrote jqyery.min.js

Comment: check the jquery file name you added y in there instead u - lol

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo in your code, should be *assets/js/jquery.min.js*